# Notify after 23 hours of VPN connection

Tags: windows-7, notification, vpn

I use Cisco VPN Client to connect to work. They have a 24 hour connection disconnect policy. VPN will disconnect in 24 hours. This causes issues with programs that use the VPN connections, I have lost work because of it. I have asked them to do way with that policy, it's some compliance thing they say.

So I’m looking for an app where I can set it up to start a timer when Cisco network adapter goes up and will notify me in some time I specify like say 23 hours. Then I will have a warning and prepare my work for the disconnect.

I might have to program this myself, but hoping there is something out there.

I’m running Windows 7.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to schedule a disconnect and reconnect at, say, 4:00 AM at night. Or create a small batch-file to dis/reconnect which you can run just before you go to work (assuming you don't work 24 hours straight ;)) As an answer/comment/thought: You could create a batch-file to connect to VPN AND automatically create a scheduled task to alert you after 23 hours. (Although when you manually dis/reconnect this alert will still be in place)

Comment: I cannot do that. VPN connection requires RSA Token Code. That code changes like every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Does your "Lease Expires" of your VPN-connection in `ipconfig /all` command reflect the correct value of that 24 hours? If so you might look for software to warn you if it is about to expires (not sure if there is software already for that). If no software could be found you could do it with a cmd-script (extracting this value and warning you, but that's more a question for stackoverflow). If the value is incorrect then what is the "Lease Obtained" of your VPN-connection? Maybe that could be used in a script (adding 23 hours) before warning you. (Just some thoughts on my part)